# I can't find the lihzahrd Temple in terraria 1.2

Tags: xbox-360, terraria-console

I've explored the the entire jungle pre-hard mode, and I killed Plantera, but it never showed up on my map.

Do I have to do it on another world, without exploring as much, or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Remember to be particularly observant of tags when you post a question. While you had correctly used the xbox-360 tag, it is especially useful to tag the game you are talking about. With my edit, any user that looks up terraria-console questions will be able to see your question, where without the tag, they would not. This should let your question reach more users, and more specifically, users equipped to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Lihzahrd's would not show up on your map, they are enemies that can be found in the Jungle Temple.

Since you've already killed Plantera try going back to the temple, they should be around there now.

You can also cause Lihzahrd's to spawn by standing in front of Lihzahrd brick wall at the entrance to the Temple, even pre-hardmode!

Answer (score 0):

Try exploring the underground jungle.You can find a Jungle/Lihzard Temple anywhere in the underground jungle.